# Passing authorization header to user email url

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to accomplish email verification through laravel api.

The Flow:
Registration -> sendEmail -> UserClickEmail Link -> EmailVerified

The Question:

How could one pass Auth token with the email for user authenitcation cause the Route is auth:api middleware protected.

By the way! I'm using laravel passport to create tokens.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but from what you've wrote and what I read in Laravel docs few minutes ago. It seems to me, that you should define other route without auth:api guard on it and generate activation links to that route.

Comment: @tomJO can you point me to your source?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#protecting-routes
There is not much, but I don't think you need an access token for creating user activation links. I'm sorry if I am talking in very generalized manner. If I were you, I would create a Route to other Controller action without making it protected with middleware.

Comment: There is already a recommended way to verify emails: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification